# how to test that the function under test has thrown an exception

Tags: scalatest, playframework-2.6

In my `scala` and `play` code, a function throws an exception

```
case None => {
            println("error in updating password info")

            throw new Exception("error in updating password info") //TODOM - refine errors. Make errors well defined. Pick from config/env file
          }
```

I want to test the above code but I don't know how to test that the `Exception` was thrown. The spec I have written is

```
  "PasswordRepository Specs" should {
    "should not add password for non-existing user" in {

      val newPassword = PasswordInfo("newHasher","newPassword",Some("newSalt"))
      when(repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository.findOne(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(Future{None}) //THIS WILL CAUSE EXCEPTION CODE TO GET EXECUTED

      val passwordRepository = new PasswordRepository(repoTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods,repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository)

      println(s"adding password ${newPassword}")
      val passwordInfo:PasswordInfo = await[PasswordInfo](passwordRepository.add(repoTestEnv.testEnv.loginInfo,newPassword))(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis"))) //add SHOULD THROW AN EXCEPTION BUT HOW DO I TEST IT???

    }
  }
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with Mockito. Check the API documentation of your testing framework/assertion library.

Comment: sorry, my bad. you are correct

Comment: Never used scala, and even less scalaTest, but the documentation has a whole section explaining how to do that: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions#expectedExceptions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JB Nizet. I must confess I was being lazy! The correct way is either to use `assertThrow` or `interrupt`. Eg.

```scala
val exception:scalatest.Assertion = assertThrows[java.lang.Exception](await[PasswordInfo(passwordRepository.add(repoTestEnv.testEnv.loginInfo,newPassword)
)(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis"))))
```

or

```scala
val exception = intercept[java.lang.Exception](await[Unit](passwordRepository.remove(repoTestEnv.testEnv.loginInfo))(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis"))))

println(s"exception is ${exception}")

exception.getMessage() mustBe repoTestEnv.testEnv.messagesApi("error.passwordDeleteError")(repoTestEnv.testEnv.langs.availables(0))
```